# Inline Regex in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some Jquery code like this:

```
$("a[for_column="+ p_column_name +"]"
```

Problem is, when p_columns_name is something like `this_table.user_name`  I need to remove everything before the `.` including the `.`.

Is this possible inline?

Comment: What about using Escape character /

Comment: `p_column_name.substring(p_column_name.indexOf('.')+1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `/.*\./` with nothing:

```
$("a[for_column="+ p_column_name.replace(/.*\./, '') +"]"
```

`.*` - everything before the last *dot*.
`\.` - the *dot* itself.

Answer (score 1):

You do not neef any regex. Use `indexOf` with `substring`:

```
$("a[for_column="+ p_column_name.substring(p_column_name.indexOf('.')+1) +"]"
```

```js
var p_column_name = "this_table.user_name";
alert(p_column_name.substring(p_column_name.indexOf('.')+1));
```